# Find min width required to display item in full with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, width, css

Is it possible to find the number of pixels that is required to display a div completely?

Right now, my div is at 100%, but I would really like it to be as small as the content... (can't use floats or other css tricks).

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense, or at least it's a bit unclear. Can you add some code?

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML.  How you would do this is quite dependent upon the content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question may be dependent upon the content so without seeing your HTML, we can only guess, but the only way that a div sizes itself to it's content is when it's `position: absolute`.

So, you can use a function like this to get a div to temporarily wrap to it's content so you can measure the content width.  You would then use that width to set it's size if you wanted:

```
function measureWidth(selector) {
    var item = $(selector).eq(0);     // just first item
    var pos = item.css("position");   // save original value
    item.css("position", "absolute");
    var width = item.width();
    item.css("position", pos);
    return(width);
}

var width = measureWidth("#header");
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/L2J5w/

FYI, I learned this technique from jQuery.  It uses it internally to measure the width of some things.  It even has an internal (non-documented) function called `.swap()` that is used for saving the values of a set of CSS properties, setting those CSS properties to something else, taking a measurement, then restoring the CSS properties to their original values.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not set the `div` width to 100% and set the `display: inline`, then it should only take as much space as the content as long as it does not overflow.

If the contents do overflow then, this will tell you the width of the div for its contents when a scrollbar is present

```
$("#mydivid")[0].scrollWidth
```